# C# Restful Client Issue

Tags: c#, rest, spring-mvc

I am having problems creating a C# Restful client to demonstrate CRUD functionality of a Spring Restful MVC server application.

The MVC server application is copied from the excellent article at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-spring3webserv/. It is deployed to Tomcat 6 running on the local host.

I have no problems

(1) using cUrl to demonstrate all CRUD functionality from my restful application

(2) using Web Browsers to demonstate reading from my restful application

(3) using my C# client to read other pages on internet.

However when my C# client is pointed at my Spring RestFul application it fails with the exception on the server being

SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet rest threw exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'employeesx' in servlet with name 'rest'
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1029)
.....

Note rest and employeesx are specific to this application.

I would welcome advice on this issue - I am fully prepared for it to be an obvious GOTCHA that I am not aware of and to take any flak coming my way!

Cheers Bill

Comment: you should post some sample code and what kind of request the server is expecting. or you could post the output of `curl -v` to demonstrate the working version

Comment: John - thank you for your response.

Comment: John - thank you for your response. As I was preparing to upload my cURL screens to post them I noticed that they were not exactly as I expected. This pointed me to the issue that was causing the problem - in the C# code I had not specified the HttpWRequest.Accept = "application/xml" - the browser and cURL applications worked around this but C# HttpWRequest approach was more rigorous and threw an exception. With this line in place all is well. As is so often the case it takes an interaction with someone else to get you back on track - thank you for that.

Comment: And check out RestSharp. It will probably make this easier for you :)